# Remove non ascii characters from a string? (in python)

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, ascii

I am trying to parse a string from an HTML file that has multiple lines that have a mix of ascii and non-ascii characters such as this:

```
"industrial light & \u003cbr\u003emagic, lucasarts"
```

I have tried to encode the string into ascii using the encode function but it only returns the same value that was put into it.

```
str = "industrial light & \u003cbr\u003emagic, lucasarts"
str.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
returns "industrial light & \u003cbr\u003emagic, lucasarts"
```

Any help woud be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It returns `industrial light & <br>magic, lucasarts ` for me

Comment: what do you want to do with that string? are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 3 I was using Python 2 that must have been the problem thank you!

Comment: I don't see *any* non-ASCII characters in that string, not in the original and not when the `\uxxxx` characters are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was trying to decode it in python 2. Python 2 and python 3 handle this kind of conversion differently. Once I tried it in python 3 everything worked fine. Thank you all for your help!